# GoldfishAddressSpaceHostMemoryAllocator: ioctl_ping failed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, logcat

After migrating to AndroidX,this code has stopped working.
Before migrating to AndroidX,this code was working.

Error :

2020-02-24 09:41:17.918 17888-17921/edmt.dev.androidgridlayout E/eglCodecCommon: GoldfishAddressSpaceHostMemoryAllocator: ioctl_ping failed for device_type=5, ret=-1

BackgroundTask.java:

```
package edmt.dev.androidgridlayout;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
    Context ctx;
    BackgroundTask(Context ctx)
    {
        this.ctx=ctx;
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(ctx,result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

//        String url="http://192.168.42.159/kamakshi/addproduct.php?name="+name+"&quantity="+quantity;
        String url="http://10.0.2.2/kamakshi/addproduct.php";

        String method = params[0];
        if (method.equals("addproduct"))
        {
            String name=params[1];
            String quantity=params[2];
            String cp=params[3];
            String sp=params[4];
            String etseller=params[5];
            String seller=params[6];
            String brand=params[7];
            String colour=params[8];
            String fabric=params[9];
            String size=params[10];
            String type=params[11];
//            String gender=params[12];


            System.out.println(method+"omkar"+name+"......"+quantity+" "+cp+" "+sp+" "+etseller+" "+seller+" "+brand+" "+colour+" "+fabric+" "+size);
            try{
                URL url1 = new URL(url);
                HttpURLConnection httpsURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url1.openConnection();
                if(httpsURLConnection!=null)
                {
                    System.out.println("connn established");

                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("connn failed");

                }
                System.out.println("connn established");
                httpsURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpsURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream os=httpsURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os,"UTF-8"));
                String data= URLEncoder.encode("name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("cp","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(cp,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("sp","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(sp,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("etseller","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(etseller,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("seller","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(seller,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("brand","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(brand,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("colour","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(colour,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("fabric","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(fabric,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("size","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(size,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("type","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(type,"UTF-8")+"&"+
//                        URLEncoder.encode("gender","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(gender,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                        URLEncoder.encode("quantity","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(quantity,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                os.close();

                InputStream IS= httpsURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(IS,"iso-8859-1"));
                br.close();
                IS.close();

                httpsURLConnection.disconnect();

            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return url;
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="edmt.dev.androidgridlayout">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".scandemo"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Scanner" />
        <activity android:name=".ProductTable" />
        <activity android:name=".ProductView" />
        <activity android:name=".addproduct" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ActivityOne" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

[image: output of logcat error]

[image: output of logcat verbose]

Comment: share your `manifest.xml` file

Comment: sir, I have updated my post and shared manifest.xml file

Comment: r u using 10.0.0.2 something as your ip to connect to that server? ALso r u trying to run your app on api pie?

Comment: yes sir, I am using 10.0.2.2 as my ip to connect to that server also using api pie.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line - `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` under the application tag of your manifest file.

I have updated the code of your manifest file with the required statement.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="edmt.dev.androidgridlayout">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".scandemo"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Scanner" />
        <activity android:name=".ProductTable" />
        <activity android:name=".ProductView" />
        <activity android:name=".addproduct" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ActivityOne" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: please can u share the exact code which is needed to be added

Comment: @Omkar Ghurye I have updated my answer to include the code snippet

Comment: It is worth mentioning that this solves the java.io.Exception. It is not related to GoldfishAddressSpaceHostMemoryAllocator message error.