# Error when connecting to native library: E/eglCodecCommon: GoldfishAddressSpaceHostMemoryAllocator: ioctl_ping failed for device_type=5, ret=-1

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface, jna

I am trying to pass data to a native C library within a Java Android app and i keep getting this error?

```
HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe209a150, tid 16633
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
E/eglCodecCommon: GoldfishAddressSpaceHostMemoryAllocator: ioctl_ping failed for device_type=5, ret=-1
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe9ce5920: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe3a70b10)
D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 3 2
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 16632 (AsyncTask #1), pid 16586 (.app.matlabtest)
```

Does anyone have any information or experience with this error, is this related to my JNA passing data at all?

I am pretty sure my JNA implementations are all in order now however i still cannot pass my data.

Full backtrace as below:

```
05-18 07:47:35.915 16586 16632 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL) in tid 16632 (AsyncTask #1), pid 16586 (.app.matlabtest)
05-18 07:47:36.136 16641 16641 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
05-18 07:47:36.136 16641 16641 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone_x86_arm/generic_x86_arm:9/PSR1.180720.117/5875966:user/release-keys'
05-18 07:47:36.136 16641 16641 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
05-18 07:47:36.136 16641 16641 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'x86'
05-18 07:47:36.136 16641 16641 F DEBUG   : pid: 16586, tid: 16632, name: AsyncTask #1  >>> com.waymap.app.matlabtest <<<
05-18 07:47:36.136 16641 16641 F DEBUG   : signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
05-18 07:47:36.136 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     eax 00000000  ebx 000040ca  ecx 000040f8  edx 00000006
05-18 07:47:36.136 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     edi 000040ca  esi d0608597
05-18 07:47:36.136 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     ebp d0261868  esp d02617f8  eip ee704b39
05-18 07:47:36.194 16641 16641 F DEBUG   : 
05-18 07:47:36.194 16641 16641 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
05-18 07:47:36.195 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 00000b39  [vdso:ee704000] (__kernel_vsyscall+9)
05-18 07:47:36.195 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 0001fdf8  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+40)
05-18 07:47:36.195 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #02 pc 00022ed3  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+115)
05-18 07:47:36.195 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #03 pc 000d295b  /data/app/com.waymap.app.matlabtest-I2nnoNIzamg5_DsTdhWXRA==/lib/x86/libcom.waymap.app.matlabtest.so (rtDynamicBoundsError+203)
05-18 07:47:36.195 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #04 pc 00033039  /data/app/com.waymap.app.matlabtest-I2nnoNIzamg5_DsTdhWXRA==/lib/x86/libcom.waymap.app.matlabtest.so
05-18 07:47:36.195 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #05 pc 000299be  /data/app/com.waymap.app.matlabtest-I2nnoNIzamg5_DsTdhWXRA==/lib/x86/libcom.waymap.app.matlabtest.so (b_dxfParseFileContentsNEW+446)
05-18 07:47:36.195 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #06 pc 000ddb06  /data/app/com.waymap.app.matlabtest-I2nnoNIzamg5_DsTdhWXRA==/lib/x86/libcom.waymap.app.matlabtest.so (mapParse+1766)
05-18 07:47:36.195 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #07 pc 000f7cc0  /data/app/com.waymap.app.matlabtest-I2nnoNIzamg5_DsTdhWXRA==/lib/x86/libcom.waymap.app.matlabtest.so (TraceMap+352)
05-18 07:47:36.195 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #08 pc 000f7480  /data/app/com.waymap.app.matlabtest-I2nnoNIzamg5_DsTdhWXRA==/lib/x86/libcom.waymap.app.matlabtest.so (TraceInitialise+112)
05-18 07:47:36.195 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #09 pc 00011129  /data/app/com.waymap.app.matlabtest-I2nnoNIzamg5_DsTdhWXRA==/lib/x86/libjnidispatch.so (ffi_call_SYSV+25)
05-18 07:47:36.195 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #10 pc 00010da0  /data/app/com.waymap.app.matlabtest-I2nnoNIzamg5_DsTdhWXRA==/lib/x86/libjnidispatch.so (ffi_call+176)
05-18 07:47:36.195 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #11 pc 000051e0  /data/app/com.waymap.app.matlabtest-I2nnoNIzamg5_DsTdhWXRA==/lib/x86/libjnidispatch.so
05-18 07:47:36.195 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #12 pc 00007d5f  /data/app/com.waymap.app.matlabtest-I2nnoNIzamg5_DsTdhWXRA==/lib/x86/libjnidispatch.so (Java_com_sun_jna_Native_invokeVoid+63)
05-18 07:47:36.195 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #13 pc 005f6a17  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline+71)
05-18 07:47:36.195 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #14 pc 005f0bd2  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+418)
05-18 07:47:36.195 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #15 pc 000a2f5f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+239)
05-18 07:47:36.195 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #16 pc 0029bb22  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+338)
05-18 07:47:36.195 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #17 pc 00293cc8  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1048)
05-18 07:47:36.195 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #18 pc 005bdb1f  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+207)
05-18 07:47:36.195 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #19 pc 005e2d21  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14625)
05-18 07:47:36.195 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #20 pc 00286478  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/com.waymap.app.matlabtest-I2nnoNIzamg5_DsTdhWXRA==/base.apk (deleted) (com.sun.jna.Function.invoke+960)
05-18 07:47:36.195 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #21 pc 00266096  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.3007865774+598)
05-18 07:47:36.195 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #22 pc 0026c61c  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+220)
05-18 07:47:36.195 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #23 pc 00293cab  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1019)
05-18 07:47:36.195 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #24 pc 005bc353  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+691)
05-18 07:47:36.195 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #25 pc 005e2ba1  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14241)
05-18 07:47:36.195 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #26 pc 002865f0  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/com.waymap.app.matlabtest-I2nnoNIzamg5_DsTdhWXRA==/base.apk (deleted) (com.sun.jna.Function.invoke+348)
05-18 07:47:36.195 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #27 pc 00266096  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.3007865774+598)
05-18 07:47:36.195 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #28 pc 0026c61c  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+220)
05-18 07:47:36.195 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #29 pc 002950a9  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<true, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+985)
05-18 07:47:36.195 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #30 pc 005bdee8  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualRange+664)
05-18 07:47:36.195 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #31 pc 005e2ea1  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+15009)
05-18 07:47:36.196 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #32 pc 00287604  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/com.waymap.app.matlabtest-I2nnoNIzamg5_DsTdhWXRA==/base.apk (deleted) (com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke+524)
05-18 07:47:36.196 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #33 pc 00266096  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.3007865774+598)
05-18 07:47:36.196 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #34 pc 0026c61c  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+220)
05-18 07:47:36.196 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #35 pc 00293cab  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1019)
05-18 07:47:36.196 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #36 pc 005bd434  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+1444)
05-18 07:47:36.196 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #37 pc 005e2da1  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14753)
05-18 07:47:36.196 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #38 pc 000cd0be  /system/framework/boot.vdex (java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke+4)
05-18 07:47:36.196 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #39 pc 00266096  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.3007865774+598)
05-18 07:47:36.196 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #40 pc 0026c50e  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*)+126)
05-18 07:47:36.196 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #41 pc 005a93fd  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1277)
05-18 07:47:36.196 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #42 pc 005f6aed  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+77)
05-18 07:47:36.196 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #43 pc 005f0bd2  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+418)
05-18 07:47:36.196 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #44 pc 000a2f5f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+239)
05-18 07:47:36.196 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #45 pc 004d3209  /system/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+89)
05-18 07:47:36.196 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #46 pc 004d402d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeWithJValues(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, jvalue*)+429)
05-18 07:47:36.196 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #47 pc 0039a9dd  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JNI::CallStaticObjectMethodA(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, jvalue*)+925)
05-18 07:47:36.196 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #48 pc 000da6c8  /system/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::CheckJNI::CallMethodA(char const*, _JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, jvalue*, art::Primitive::Type, art::InvokeType)+1720)
05-18 07:47:36.197 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #49 pc 000c6039  /system/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::CheckJNI::CallStaticObjectMethodA(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, jvalue*)+73)
05-18 07:47:36.197 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #50 pc 00586103  /system/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeProxyInvocationHandler(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable&, char const*, _jobject*, _jobject*, std::__1::vector<jvalue, std::__1::allocator<jvalue>>&)+627)
05-18 07:47:36.197 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #51 pc 005aa4e7  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickProxyInvokeHandler+1335)
05-18 07:47:36.197 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #52 pc 005f6746  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_proxy_invoke_handler+54)
05-18 07:47:36.197 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #53 pc 005f0a02  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+338)
05-18 07:47:36.197 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #54 pc 000a2f4e  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+222)
05-18 07:47:36.197 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #55 pc 0029bb22  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+338)
05-18 07:47:36.197 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #56 pc 002950c6  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<true, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1014)
05-18 07:47:36.197 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #57 pc 005bf044  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterfaceRange+1444)
05-18 07:47:36.197 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #58 pc 005e30a1  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+15521)
05-18 07:47:36.197 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #59 pc 002965a2  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/com.waymap.app.matlabtest-I2nnoNIzamg5_DsTdhWXRA==/base.apk (deleted) (com.waymap.app.matlabtest.MainActivity$1.run+34)
05-18 07:47:36.244 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #60 pc 00266096  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.3007865774+598)
05-18 07:47:36.246 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #61 pc 0026c61c  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+220)
05-18 07:47:36.253 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #62 pc 00293cab  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1019)
05-18 07:47:36.253 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #63 pc 005bd434  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+1444)
05-18 07:47:36.253 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #64 pc 005e2da1  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14753)
05-18 07:47:36.255 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #65 pc 00ad5c2c  /system/framework/boot-framework.vdex (android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run+4)
05-18 07:47:36.255 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #66 pc 00266096  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.3007865774+598)
05-18 07:47:36.255 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #67 pc 0026c61c  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+220)
05-18 07:47:36.255 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #68 pc 00293cab  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1019)
05-18 07:47:36.255 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #69 pc 005bd434  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+1444)
05-18 07:47:36.255 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #70 pc 005e2da1  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14753)
05-18 07:47:36.255 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #71 pc 00117114  /system/framework/boot.vdex (java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker+162)
05-18 07:47:36.256 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #72 pc 00266096  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.3007865774+598)
05-18 07:47:36.256 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #73 pc 0026c61c  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+220)
05-18 07:47:36.256 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #74 pc 00293cab  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1019)
05-18 07:47:36.256 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #75 pc 005bc353  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+691)
05-18 07:47:36.256 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #76 pc 005e2ba1  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14241)
05-18 07:47:36.257 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #77 pc 00116442  /system/framework/boot.vdex (java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run+4)
05-18 07:47:36.257 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #78 pc 00266096  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.3007865774+598)
05-18 07:47:36.257 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #79 pc 0026c61c  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+220)
05-18 07:47:36.257 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #80 pc 00293cab  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1019)
05-18 07:47:36.259 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #81 pc 005bd434  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+1444)
05-18 07:47:36.259 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #82 pc 005e2da1  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14753)
05-18 07:47:36.259 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #83 pc 000ca806  /system/framework/boot.vdex (java.lang.Thread.run+12)
05-18 07:47:36.259 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #84 pc 00266096  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.3007865774+598)
05-18 07:47:36.259 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #85 pc 0026c50e  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*)+126)
05-18 07:47:36.259 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #86 pc 005a93fd  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1277)
05-18 07:47:36.259 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #87 pc 005f6aed  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+77)
05-18 07:47:36.259 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #88 pc 005f0a02  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+338)
05-18 07:47:36.259 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #89 pc 000a2f4e  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+222)
05-18 07:47:36.259 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #90 pc 004d3209  /system/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+89)
05-18 07:47:36.259 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #91 pc 004d44b7  /system/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, jvalue*)+471)
05-18 07:47:36.259 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #92 pc 0050944c  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+1484)
05-18 07:47:36.259 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #93 pc 0008f065  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+53)
05-18 07:47:36.260 16641 16641 F DEBUG   :     #94 pc 0002485b  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+75)
```

It must be somethign in the way i am mapping to the emxArray_char_T structure which i:

```
@Structure.FieldOrder({ "str", "size", "allocatedSize", "numDimensions", "canFreeData"})
public class emxArray_char_T extends Structure implements Structure.ByReference{


    public Pointer str;
    public Pointer size;
    public int allocatedSize;
    public int numDimensions;
    public int canFreeData;

    //Static
    public emxArray_char_T(Pointer str, Pointer size) {
        this.str = str;
        this.size = size;
    }

    //Dynamic
    public emxArray_char_T(Pointer str, Pointer size, int allocatedSize, int numDimensions, int canFreeData) {
        this.str = str;
        this.size = size;
        this.allocatedSize = allocatedSize;
        this.numDimensions = numDimensions;
        this.canFreeData = canFreeData;
    }

    public emxArray_char_T() {
    }
}
```

to map to the matlab struct as i have mentioned:

```
struct emxArray_char_T
{
  char *data;
  int *size;
  int allocatedSize;
  int numDimensions;
  bool canFreeData;
};
```

The documentation: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/use-c-arrays-in-the-generated-function-interfaces.html#mw_0cae9a4a-b74d-43f9-aae0-ed192db73d22

I pass the Size pointer which is to an int[] which is my only worry as:

```
Pointer PTRinitialDynamicSize = new Memory(2*Native.getNativeSize(Integer.TYPE));
        PTRinitialDynamicSize.setInt(0*Native.getNativeSize(Integer.TYPE),1);
        PTRinitialDynamicSize.setInt(1*Native.getNativeSize(Integer.TYPE), initialDynamicAllocatedSize);

        Pointer PTRallFloorsSize = new Memory(2*Native.getNativeSize(Integer.TYPE));
        PTRallFloorsSize.setInt(0*Native.getNativeSize(Integer.TYPE),1);
        PTRallFloorsSize.setInt(1*Native.getNativeSize(Integer.TYPE), allFloorsAllocatedSize);
```

Comment: Something inside `b_dxfParseFileContentsNEW` seems to be accessing something out of bounds. Without seeing the source to that, we cannot help you.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60369614/goldfishaddressspacehostmemoryallocator-ioctl-ping-failed which had similar symptom

Comment: Your static structure constructor leaves some fields uninitialized.  `numDimensions` is 0 and `canFreeData` is false.  Not sure if that causes problems.

Comment: @DanielWiddis Thanks, yes i pass the dynamic one or i certainly provide the 5 fields in my code. I have spent today stepping through the native code and it seems the issue is with the data provided which is good news for my implementation. This looks good now as far as code goes. Don't worry i am sure i will have more questions very soon! Thank for the help.

Comment: @Botje you were right the issue was in the file you suggested the data being provided needed work on it. Thank you.